# Chaining redux action creator Promise.then() in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm planning on using axios for async calls and promises in my redux action creators. Currently there is not yet an API which can be used so I am keeping things locally.

How can I make the following chainable from inside a react component?

**Action creators**

```
export function fetchResultsIfNeeded() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (true) {
            return dispatch(fetchResults(day, hash));
        }

        else {return Promise.resolve();}
    };
}

export function fetchResults(day, hash) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // Dispatch something here

        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
            // Do some stuff here
            // Dispatch some other stuff here as well
        }); // Want to chain on this promise in react component
    };
}
```

**React component**

```
import { fetchResultsIfNeeded } from 'actions';

// Class based react component
checkResults(periodFrom, periodTo) {
    this.props.fetchResultsIfNeeded([periodFrom, periodTo]).then(() => {/* Do some stuff here */});
}

// Connected via react redux
export default connect(null, { fetchResultsIfNeeded })(component);
```

Currently receiving the following error, can it be that it is still waiting on react-redux or so?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Put the action creator and component in a Pen (not sure how to show full code otherwise)

[Full component code](http://codepen.io/nealoke/pen/VPLprX), [Full action creator code](http://codepen.io/nealoke/pen/BpNWmb)

Comment: This looks correct to me. Did you maybe forget to install the `redux-thunk` middleware?

Comment: @Jacob nope, using this for a while on this app :)

Comment: Could you post a more complete example of the React component? Perhaps the problem is somewhere in there.

Comment: @Jacob See updated question ;)

Comment: make sure the then() inside fetchResults() returns a promise

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @MichaelFulton check the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `redux-thunk`. You need to return from the resolve function inside your action creator. The correct flow should be:

```js
export function fetchResults(day, hash) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        
        dispatch(...).then(
             ( ) => {
                 // Do some stuff here
                 return dispatch(...)
             }
        )            
    }
}
```

Comment: But the `fetchResults ` should return a promise, so not another dispatch in there. See the usage in the react component please :)

Comment: sorry, it's a bit late for me, I did not see the component, nor the connect usage

Comment: No worries, I am just wondering why it is not working, even if I do `console.log(this.props.fetchResultsIfNeeded) ` in the component, it returns `undefined`. I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: maybe check the path of the 'actions.js' file, if the prop is undefined, it means that `connect` is not working

Comment: Doublechecked the path, is correct though. Any other ideas?

Comment: if `this.props.fetchResultsIfNeeded` is undefined, how can you call it inside `checkResults` ? you should get `undefined is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

There's more than one way to do this, but perhaps the simplest way to do so with your existing code is to use `bindActionCreators`:

```
import { fetchResultsIfNeeded } from 'actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

// Class based react component
checkResults(periodFrom, periodTo) {
    this.props.fetchResultsIfNeeded([periodFrom, periodTo]).then(() => {/* Do some stuff here */});
}

// Connected via react redux
export default connect(
  null,
  dispatch => ({
    ...bindActionCreators({ fetchResultsIfNeeded }, dispatch)
  })
)(component);
```

Comment: The `connect` call being used definitely works in my projects; the more verbose action creator binding _shouldn't_ be necessary.

Comment: True, but without bindActionCreators, he'd need to wrap the action in dispatch().  like:  dispatch(this.props.fetchResultsIfNeeded(...)).then(...)  But you need a reference dispatch, which you usually pass in via connect() (thus requiring passing a function as mapDispatchToProps instead of an object:  connect(null, dispatch => { fetchResultsIfNeeded, dispatch })  )

Comment: `react-redux` automatically does `bindActionCreators` if you pass an object for connecting to actions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now @Jacob, do I still need to to the suggestion or not?

Comment: I don't think you need to do this suggestion; my only guess here is that the original `fetchResultsIfNeeded` isn't a function or that there's something bizarre about your component, because what you've posted so far is the exact same pattern we use, and it's been working fine.

Comment: This is not directly addressing the problem of the question. It's good to use bindActionCreators but it's not necessary at all.